# Restart Django production server (passenger wsgi)

Tags: django

I uploaded a modified views.py to the production server, but it's still using the old code.  I also deleted the views.pyc and views.py to see if it'd clear it's old cached python code.  That worked after a while of waiting the past few times, but I really want to know how to do things quickly.  The site is hosted on dreamhost and is using passenger wsgi.

How do I quickly and manually restart it so that it'll use my new views.py code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django#Hints

> If you modified your application and
>   your changes do not seem to be
>   reflected, you may need to notify
>   Passenger about your change by
>   creating or modifying
>   ~/example.com/tmp/restart.txt:

```
touch /home/user/example.com/tmp/restart.txt
```

> Passenger looks for this file and
>   reloads the application when this file
>   is modified.

Comment: Dude, thanks a million.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  It reloaded my code right away!  XD!